# Is there a way to trigger CSS max-width @media query without resizing browser window?

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

My website has `<body>` container `max-width` set to 1000px and `width` to 100% which makes it display fine on all resolutions from 100px to 4000px (and more) - it's responsive.

I use `@media` queries to tell elements (such as columns) on that website to become 100% wide below `max-width: 800px` (so for mobile phones). Example:

```
.column { width: 50%; float: left; }
@media (max-width: 800px){
.column { width: 100%; }
}
```

**What I want is to see mobile phone version of website on 1920px monitor. Is there a way to achieve this without resizing browser window to <800px?**

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You need to resize the browser window to the size you want in order to simulate a smaller screen.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there are any workarounds perhaps? I really need to show mobile phone version of website on all resolutions without necessity to resize browser window.

Comment: Yes, actually, now I think about it. You can put the page in an iframe. The iframe's size will be used to resolve media queries.

Comment: Thanks! That's good suggestion. I'd prefer not to use iframes because they would limit me but I think I could leverage them to be what I want.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol, this idea actually saved me too!

Answer (score 1):

Try out this handy tool. It allows you to view the site in several different widths. http://responsive.victorcoulon.fr/

Comment: Very cool! I think that this may be something I need. Although it seems to be iframe based which is not what I necessarily want. Thanks for the link!